# Intellij Idea automatically changing the name of the project

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij idea is automatically changing the name of the project to one of the module that is imported. Is this a feature that can be disabled somewhere?

Steps:

- Create project
- Import module - maven - A
- import another module - maven -B
- project name is changed to 'A'.

This has happened to several other projects i have. I'm on the latest version of Intellij community edition. 2020.3

Answer (score 1):

It is known issue: [IDEA-230219](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230219).